# Is it possible to pattern match on a by-name parameter without evaluating it?

Tags: scala, purely-functional

Was playing with Lazy Structure Stream as below

```
import Stream._

sealed trait Stream[+A] {
    ..
    def toList: List[A] = this match {
        case Empty => Nil
        case Cons(h, t) => println(s"${h()}::t().toList"); h()::t().toList
    }
    def foldRight[B](z: B) (f: ( A, => B) => B) : B = this match {
        case Empty => println(s"foldRight of Empty return $z"); z
        case Cons(h, t) => println(s"f(${h()}, t().foldRight(z)(f))"); f(h(), t().foldRight(z)(f))
    }
    ..
}
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

object Stream {

    def cons[A](h: => A, t: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
        lazy val hd = h
        lazy val tl = t
        Cons[A](() => hd, () => tl)
    }

    def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

    def apply[A](la: A*): Stream[A] = la match {
        case list if list.isEmpty => empty[A]
        case _ => cons(la.head, apply(la.tail:_*))
    }

}
```

For a function takeWhile via foldRight i initially wrote:

```
def takeWhileFoldRight_0(p: A => Boolean) : Stream[A] = {
        foldRight(empty[A]) {
                case (a, b) if p(a) => println(s"takeWhileFoldRight cons($a, b) with p(a) returns: cons($a, b)"); cons(a, b)
                case (a, b) if !p(a) => println(s"takeWhileFoldRight cons($a, b) with !p(a) returns: empty[A]"); empty[A]
            }
        }
```

Which when called as:

```
Stream(4,5,6).takeWhileFoldRight_0(_%2 == 0).toList
```

result in the following trace:

```
f(4, t().foldRight(z)(f))
f(5, t().foldRight(z)(f))
f(6, t().foldRight(z)(f))
foldRight of Empty return Empty
takeWhileFoldRight cons(6, b) with p(a) returns: cons(6, b)
takeWhileFoldRight cons(5, b) with !p(a) returns: empty[A]
takeWhileFoldRight cons(4, b) with p(a) returns: cons(4, b)
4::t().toList
res2: List[Int] = List(4)
```

Then questioning and questioning i figured that it might have been the unapply method in the pattern match that evaluate eagerly.

So i changed  to

```
def takeWhileFoldRight(p: A => Boolean) : Stream[A] = {
        foldRight(empty[A]) { (a, b) =>
            if (p(a)) cons(a, b) else empty[A]
        }
    }
```

which when called as

```
Stream(4,5,6).takeWhileFoldRight(_%2 == 0).toList
```

result in the following trace:

```
f(4, t().foldRight(z)(f))
4::t().toList
f(5, t().foldRight(z)(f))
res1: List[Int] = List(4)
```

Hence my question:

Is there a way to recover the power of pattern match when working with by-name parameter ?

Said differently case i match parameter that are by-name without evaluating them eagerly ?

Or i have to go to a set of ugly nested "if" :p in that kind of scenario

Answer (score 2):

Take a closer look at this fragment:

```
    def toList: List[A] = this match {
        case Empty => Nil
        case Cons(h, t) => println(s"${h()}::t().toList"); h()::t().toList
    }
    def foldRight[B](z: B) (f: ( A, => B) => B) : B = this match {
        case Empty => println(s"foldRight of Empty return $z"); z
        case Cons(h, t) => println(s"f(${h()}, t().foldRight(z)(f))"); f(h(), t().foldRight(z)(f))
    }
    ..
}
```

Here `h` and `t` in `Cons` aren't evaluated by `unapply` - after all `unapply` returns `() => X` functions without calling them. But you do. Twice for each match - once for printing and once for passing the result on. And you aren't remembering the result, so any future fold, map, etc would evaluate the function anew.

Depending on what behavior you want to have you should either:

1. Calculate the results once, right after matching them:

```
case Cons(h, t) =>
  val hResult = h()
  val tResult = t()
  println(s"${hResult}::tail.toList")
  hResult :: tResult.toList
```

or

2. not use `case class` because it cannot memoize the result and you might need to memoize it:

```
class Cons[A](fHead: () => A, fTail: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A] {
  lazy val head: A = fHead()
  lazy val tail: Stream[A] = fTail()
  // also override: toString, equals, hashCode, ...
}
object Cons {
  def apply[A](head: => A, tail: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] =
    new Cons(() => head, () => tail)
  def unapply[A](stream: Stream[A]): Option[(A, Stream[A])] = stream match {
    case cons: Cons[A] => Some((cons.head, cons.tail)) // matches on type, doesn't use unapply
    case _             => None
  }
}
```

3. If you understand what you're doing you could also create a `case class` with overridden `apply` and `unapply` (like above) but that is almost always a signal that you shouldn't use a case class in the first place (because most likely `toString`, `equals`, `hashCode`, etc would have nonsensical implementation).

Comment: Hummm i some how disagree with the premise of your answer already. Cons that two no argument functions. Those not by-name parameter. So I am matching functions in the case of Cons. I am only calling them when I need to evaluate them. I only call h() for printing and that is ok because it will be evaluated eagerly. And this is just for playing around and understanding the behavior.

Comment: The problem is not with Cons which works as intended. It is with the (a,b) in take while, which is a product and do not have thunk parameter hence evaluate them

Comment: So I guess a way to solve it would be to use the same trick in the f function of foldRight. Instead of =>B I SHOULD USE ()=>B

Comment: Neither `h()` nor `t()` memoize. So `h(); h()` will evaluate head twice. If you put a `println` there you will `println` twice. `unapply` merely extracts values from function, it doesn't distinct functions from non-functions so that it would call them. `case class`es doesn't support `lazy val`s, so the bottom line is that you would either recalculate and require some carefulness to avoid double calculation or you should not use case class in the first place, to allow yourself to memoize.

Comment: You are right about h but I know and did it on purpose. Beside I don’t know if you realize that foldRight is not the issue here, fundamentally. The issue is between the two version of takeWhilefoldRight. One use pattern matching on the parameter and the other one use if and it makes a difference ..... that is where the question was ....

Comment: But readying between i guess your answer is no you can’t recover here because a pair is a product which is a case class which evaluate eagerly

Comment: So can’t use the trick if product for fast if then evaluation

Comment: A possible solution http://www.scala-archive.org/scala-Lazy-tuple-td1990380.html